# Arduino keypad.getState() seems to not be behaving correctly

Tags: c++, arduino

So we're trying to build an interface for Arduino and Kerbal and we're successful in emulating key presses BUT not hold presses. The code below seems to print "NOT HOLDING " before printing "holding " correctly successive times. The problem with this is that its like pressing the button twice rather than pressing it once and holding.

Our hunch is that some logic is wrong somewhere but i cant seem to get it correctly.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Keyboard.h>

char previousPressedKey;
boolean hasReleasedKey = false;

const byte ROWS = 6; //four rows
    const byte COLS = 6; //four columns
    //define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypads
    char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
      {'w','i','1','7','c','v'},
      {'a','j','2','8','m','u'},
      {'s','k','3','9',',','.'},
      {'d','l','4','0','z','x'},
      {'e','h','5','t','b','g'},
      {'q','n','6','r','y','o'},

    };
    byte rowPins[ROWS] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
    byte colPins[COLS] = {16, 15, 14, 9, 8, 7}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
// -- Keypad related ends

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop(){
  delay(50);
  keypadLoop();
}  

void keypadLoop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  KeyState state = keypad.getState();

  if (state == HOLD){
    // if key is held
    //Keyboard.println(key);
    //Keyboard.println(previousPressedKey);
    Keyboard.println("holding ");
  }

  if (state == PRESSED && key != NO_KEY) {
    //previousPressedKey = key;
    hasReleasedKey = true;
    //Keyboard.print(key);
    Keyboard.print("NOT HOLDING ");
  }

}
```

This outputs:

```
NOT HOLDING holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding
```

When the expected output is:

```
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding 
holding
```

Comment: whats wrong with it? you have to press the key before you can hold it, no?

Comment: After you press a key the state changes to PRESSED. After some time (HoldTime) the state changes to HOLD. You can change the HoldTime with `setHoldTime`. https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad/

Comment: our issue seems to be its like pressing the button "twice" before it holds. our ideal would be to press it once AND holds. just like a regular keyboard.

Comment: ok so we've set the value to `keypad.setHoldTime(100);` that kinda worked, the RCS (booster) is turning on like how you press it on the keyboard but our worry now is that the behaviour of the other keys might be affected.

Comment: *note* also removed the `delay(50);` that should not be there.